# About the empty-set and rules about it

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $\emptyset$ a set of ordred triplets, pairs? is it a set of any property we will name (Maybe "the set of elephants" - **with no elephants** )?

I get that not all adjectives / properties can describe it, such as "the class with the number 1 in it" - not the empty set for sure, but what about the properties I wrote above?

I think that it isn't - because it doesn't have any elements - so it does not have any ordered pairs or triplets, but maybe it is because it has nothing then we cannot decide - so the answer is yes?

I am really confused by this question, I would appreciate your help!

Comment: $\emptyset$ is certainly not the set of all elephants (unless there are no elephants). But it is *a* set of elephants. Do you see the difference?

Comment: @Alex: I mean, this presumes that elephants are mathematical objects. I suppose some kind of a monster model?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I meant that it is a set of something (not all) with nothing in it. I will change this. "The empty set is a set of something with nothing in it" such as the set of the numbers modulo 3 with no numbers, is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly not characterize the empty set as the set of all ordered pairs or triplets, or $n$-tuples of any kind. However, you can characterize the empty set in several ways. One way that is sometimes used in courses in introductory set theory is the following: If you have some universe $\mathcal{U}$, you can use the seperation axiom to construct the empty set like this

$$ \emptyset = \{ x \in \mathcal{U} \, | x \neq x \}.$$

However, this is just a "trick" that I think for most people brings no intuition or deeper understanding. The empty set is simply the set which has no elements. You could also construct it as follows, assuming the same universe $\mathcal{U}$:

$$\forall x \in \mathcal{U} \quad x \notin \emptyset.$$

This is however less rigorous, and if possible, even less didactic, so forget about it now that you have seen it. Finally, addressing your question as to whether you can say that the empty set is a set of "something", you could actualy say that about anything since the empty set is a subset of every set, i.e.

$$\forall A \quad \emptyset \subseteq A,$$

(do you see why?).

Comment: But if you say that the empty set is a set of something - then why it isn't a set of ordered pairs (with NO ordered pairs) ? (I mean, the property in its "nothing form")

Comment: You are right, it is a set of ordered pairs with no ordered pairs. The question is if we achieve anything meaningful from that insight.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)